# resample time data from list data in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-resample

I have a list data like bellow which has 6 things in each element in list

```
"timestamp , open , high , low , close, volume"
```

```
['1606470300000,244.25,244.25,244.00,244.00,489269', 
 '1606470360000,244.05,244.30,244.00,244.15,452854', 
 '1606470420000,244.15,244.20,244.00,244.10,403043', 
 '1606470480000,244.15,244.15,243.95,244.00,370182', 
 '1606470540000,244.05,244.20,244.00,244.15,445286', 
 '1606470600000,244.15,244.25,244.05,244.20,473342', 
 '1606470660000,244.25,244.35,244.00,244.05,491117', 
 '1606470720000,244.05,244.20,244.00,244.20,298261', 
 '1606470780000,244.20,244.25,244.10,244.25,344172', 
 '1606470840000,244.20,244.35,244.20,244.30,347080', 
 '1606470900000,244.30,244.40,244.25,244.30,447630', 
 '1606470960000,244.30,244.30,244.00,244.00,360666', 
 '1606471020000,244.05,244.15,243.95,243.95,467724',
 '1606471080000,243.95,244.10,243.70,244.00,386080', 
 '1606471140000,244.00,244.20,243.70,244.20,166559']
```

this is a 1 minute data and I want to convert it in 15 minute data

please help

Comment: Pandas Interpolate should do.

Comment: could you please help me with this

Comment: your question is uunclear. do u want to regroup ur data by 15mins ? if so read about `dataframe.resample`

Comment: yes @ombk want to regroup  data by 15mins and I know doing this from csv file but dont know how to do it from list of data . could you please help me

Comment: you better work to let us help (not do for) you... so please add what you've been trying so far and explain what 15 minutes mean al all? this question is unclear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
list_data = ['1606470300000,244.25,244.25,244.00,244.00,489269',
 '1606470360000,244.05,244.30,244.00,244.15,452854',
 '1606470420000,244.15,244.20,244.00,244.10,403043',
 '1606470480000,244.15,244.15,243.95,244.00,370182',
 '1606470540000,244.05,244.20,244.00,244.15,445286',
 '1606470600000,244.15,244.25,244.05,244.20,473342',
 '1606470660000,244.25,244.35,244.00,244.05,491117',
 '1606470720000,244.05,244.20,244.00,244.20,298261',
 '1606470780000,244.20,244.25,244.10,244.25,344172',
 '1606470840000,244.20,244.35,244.20,244.30,347080',
 '1606470900000,244.30,244.40,244.25,244.30,447630',
 '1606470960000,244.30,244.30,244.00,244.00,360666',
 '1606471020000,244.05,244.15,243.95,243.95,467724',
 '1606471080000,243.95,244.10,243.70,244.00,386080',
 '1606471140000,244.00,244.20,243.70,244.20,166559']

# Convert to usable a dataframe  
df = pd.DataFrame(list_data)\
         .loc[:, 0]\
         .str.rsplit(",", expand=True)
df.columns = ["timestamp" , "open" , "high" , "low" , "close", "volume"]
df.loc[:, "timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp.astype(int)*1e6)
df = df.set_index("timestamp")
df = df.astype(float)

# That is how it looks like
df.head()
                       open    high     low   close    volume
timestamp                                                    
2020-11-27 09:45:00  244.25  244.25  244.00  244.00  489269.0
2020-11-27 09:46:00  244.05  244.30  244.00  244.15  452854.0
2020-11-27 09:47:00  244.15  244.20  244.00  244.10  403043.0
2020-11-27 09:48:00  244.15  244.15  243.95  244.00  370182.0
2020-11-27 09:49:00  244.05  244.20  244.00  244.15  445286.0


# resample to 15 min data
df.resample("15min").mean()
```

Comment: excellent job. I was too lazy to write it all tbh

Comment: thank you so much @Alex everything is fine but its giving error OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long could you please help

Comment: ok thank you all guys and specialy @Alex for your answer error was solved with changing int to 'int64' thank you again

Comment: thank you @Alex one more thing this time stamp starts from 15.15 and ends on 15.29 but in this solution it is in different could you tell me reason or solution for that

Comment: @AmitSharma There was a mistake in the answer. It is not `resample("15m")` (which would mean 15 months) but `resample("15min")`.